# Twitter bootstrap 3 disabled cursor appearing on top of drop down options in IE 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I've got a drop down list directly above a disabled twitter bootstrap 'form-control' input element.

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option> Option 1 </option>
        <option> Option 2 </option>
        <option> Option 3 </option>
        <option> Option 4 </option>
        <option> Option 5 </option>
        <option> Option 6 </option>
        <option> Option 7 </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="Disabled input here..." disabled="" />
</div>
```

In Internet Explorer 11 when I click on the drop down and hover over options that are in front of the disabled input the cursor changes to the red stop sign.

[image]

Demo (try in IE11): http://jsfiddle.net/Lrupx0ca/

I have only noticed this behaviour in IE11. Chrome, Firefox & IE10 seem to be ok. Any thoughts on what is going on? and any suggestions on how to fix/workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello This is IE Bug on select disable cursor

Please check this link to more understand

See IE Feedback point link https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/963961

and also see about this bug discuses link:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14528

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little late, but there will still be people searching for a solution to this problem as Microsoft still hasn't fixed the issue.

The only thing you can do to avoid this is setting the cursor-style of the disabled input element to default. In this case, it could look like this:

```
.form-control:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Note that this is strictly not a fix but a workaround to avoid ugly looking dropdowns.